# UITextView set a minimum number of lines to display

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have created a UITextView with a border background using QuartzCore. When the view is loaded the textview is shown with 3 lines. What is the best way to initialise the textview with say a minimum of 5 lines?

Comment: If UITextView _has_ 5 lines of content, it _displays_ 5 lines of content. So how about just adding two blank lines to its content?

Comment: Hi Matt, I wanted to vary the number of lines dependant on the user device.

Comment: Then vary it. At this point, I'm not following what the question is (and have voted to close it on the grounds that it isn't clear what's being asked).